# how to increase inserts speed in InnoDB Table in MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby, database

My Task is to populate couple of InnoDB tables in MySql database with random data for some performance evaluations(target is 500GB each table).

I have put partitions(31 each, equally distributed) on both these table. After generating around 40 GB data in each table, now my inserts are stuck at around 150 inserts per second and table. I believe the configuration I have on server(120GB RAM, 40 core CPU 3GHz each, SDA disk), I should be able to insert more.

There are lot of indexes on these table which can slow it down.

I am using a Ruby script in following ways:

- insert queries with multiple values in each query
- Writing data in a file than doing load-data-infile query
- A mix of both of these with 100-300 values per insert query and 3000 rows in load-data-infile file.

Using multiple instances of above scripts also does not increase the inserts per second in the table.

Following are key configuration in DB:

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size : 1G  
innodb_buffer_pool_size : 75G    
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit : 2 
innodb_doublewrite : OFF  
tx_isolation : READ-UNCOMMITTED    
foreign_key_checks : OFF    
unique_checks : OFF
```

Please let me know, what are other things I can do to increase inserts, As I believe MySql can handle way more than this. I have went through other related posts, and did above based on these.

Schema: http://pastebin.com/EaSyFX1j

Comment: Are you able to post your table scheme?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the limiting factor is. You say that there are many indexes on the table. It is well known that indexes slow down insert and update operations. Maybe it would be faster to drop the indexes, insert the data and recreate the indexes afterwards (do not delete primary and unique indexes, but only regular indexes.

Comment: I thought about that, but as I have a target of populating 500GB of data, After generating this much, I will not have space to to alter it, as it will require same amount of space to alter it(for tmp table), which I will not have.

Comment: It will not need to copy the table. You only need space for the indexes.

Comment: Also, Shouldn't partitioning had helped in reducing overhead due to indexes, I have 31 partitions will almost equal data in each partition.